# Count number of purchase occurrences given a group ID

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables (orders & merchants) where Idx is present in both
I want to have output as a table specifying how many (count) purchases that were made from the merchants belonging to the merchantgroup merchantx, given that a purchase is made when order.purchaseamount>0

```
select count(*)
from orders
inner join merchant on merchant.Idx=order.Idx
where order.purchaseamount>0
group by merchantgroup
```

There are roughly 1.3m rows in "orders", but when I group them by merchantgroup I receive a count that is way larger than that, over all the groups?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That could only make a difference if there are NULL values in merchant.idx.

Comment: First you have syntax error, which is order.purchaseamount>0 should be orders.purchaseamount>0 .